# Converting Single-Letter amino Acids in string to Molecular weights

Tags: python

So what I am supposed to do is somehow input a string composed of the single-letter representation of amino acids, then get an ouput of the total molecular weight. In my code, I already have a dictionary with the single letter amino acids as keys and the individual molecular weights as the values. Could you give me an outline to get me started on what to specify under the class I named "MolecularWeight"? And how can I get a sum of the molecular weights if the amino acids could possibly occur more than once in the string? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, in order to get answer, please read and follow this [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
def getWeight(input_string):
   sum=0
   for letter in input_string:
      sum+=weight_dict[letter]
   return sum
```

would probably do. You don't really need a class for this.